# Firebase + flamelink + angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I have hooked up firebase and flamelink and added two schemas in flamelink. blog and home. I am looking to manage website content so there is only a need for read access.

[image: firebase database]

I would like to read the data in my Angular 5.4.1 frontend but this is where things start be get fuzzy. From what I can see AngularFireList has replaced FirebaseListObservable but I don't quite get how I need to use it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, 
     AngularFireList,
    } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public db:AngularFireDatabase){
    this.items = db.list('/flamelink/environments/production/content/blog/en-US/').valueChanges();
    console.log(this.items); 
  }
}
```

This is what is logged in the console, I also get an error if I set items to type AngularFireList

[image: displayed ion the console]

[image: project settings]

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#using-angularfirestoredocument) for AngularFire, easiest way to use it would be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Item { name: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ (item | async)?.name }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;
  item: Observable<Item>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemDoc = afs.doc<Item>('items/1');
    this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
  }
  update(item: Item) {
    this.itemDoc.update(item);
  }
}
```

Another way would be to `subscribe` to the [observable](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges) that `valueChanges()` returns and complete the functionality yourself.

```
this.itemDoc.valueChanges().subscribe((item) => this.item = item);
```

This would fire whenever there is a change in value and update the `this.item` property.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work with the setup shown above. As this was just a demo I deleted the project and started again. For anyone else struggling with this, see the setup below.

[image: current setup]

Then in my app component

```
export class AppComponent {
  bs: Observable<any[]>;
  posts = [];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.bs = db.list(environment.baseURL).valueChanges();

    this.bs.subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }
```

}

Now it is working!